# R equivalent for df.values

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I have a numeric dataframe read from a `csv` file in this way:

```
df <- read.csv(path, sep=",", row.names = 1, header=TRUE)
```

So the first line is used as header and the first column is the index. I want to do something like the `python` function `df.values`, namely returns a matrix with only the numeric values.

I have tried

```
X = matrix(df)
X = data.matrix(df)
```

But none of them returns what I want i.e for instance I am not able to get the first numeric value by calling `X[1,1]`.

To clarify, I have created a data frame as follows:

Firstly, I have created the matrix with

```
X = matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

Then the `data.frame` by using

```
df_dummy = data.frame(X, row.names = c("A","B","C"))
```

And what I get with the two mentioned method is:

```
> X = matrix(df_dummy)
> X[1,1]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

And

```
> X = data.matrix(df_dummy)
> X[1,1]
[1] 1
> X
  X1 X2
A  1  4
B  2  5
C  3  6
```

So `X` is not only numerics, it still has the labels.

What I would like to have is what I built at the beginning, namely:

```
X
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

A walk around would be to create an empty matrix and fill in with a for loop, but it would be great to avoid this and find something more efficient.

Thank you for any answer, I am trying to learn `R` from scratch using my knowledge in `python`!

Comment: Why are you not able to get what you need by subsetting what are you getting instead? A `dput` of `df` and what you expect to get would also be helpful.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I have added some clarification, hope this helps! Thank you!

Comment: `as.matrix`, not `matrix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean by?

```
data.matrix(sapply(df, as.numeric))
```

Without column names:

```
unname(data.matrix(sapply(df, as.numeric)))
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to work as I expect. It is not fully clear to me why it remain the columns names. Thank you!